# How can I read .gml extension file in Python?

Tags: python, networkx

I tried installing networkx==3.1 (library which is compatible with python 3.9.4).

When I try to use the function read_gml('myfile.gml') it gives me error

> NetworkXError: cannot tokenize
> at (1, 1)

Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: There might be something wrong with the file itself. GML files are text files so you can pop one open in a text editor to see if it looks how its supposed to.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I solved my problem using another library 'geopandas' which read_file function can open it correctly.